# How to animate .html() on click

Tags: jquery

When I click this button, I'd like the to animate the .html() to make the width transition from Expand to Collapse smoother.

Here's my button:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-form">Expand</a>
```

Here's my jquery:

```
$('.toggle-form').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).html('Collapse');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Expand');
    }
});
```

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a time parameter to `show()` and `hide()` as

```
$(this).show("fast");
```

Or

```
$(this).show(500);
```

More documentation [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

There are other methods using CSS transition effects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.slideUp()** and **.slideDown()** or **.animate()** jQuery methods to achieve this.

references: http://api.jquery.com/slideup/, http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/, http://api.jquery.com/animate/